# MP4 file seeking problem from direct URL

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mp4, h.264, expression-encoder

I'm running Silverlight 4, and player is the one came with Expression 3 templates to play a file directly from URL i.e. http://mysite.com/video1.mp4. The file is encoded using Expression Encoder 3 by applying a preset from h.264 under 'Encoding for Silverlight'.

The very first problem I encountered was that video doesn't play until it downloads completely, which turned out to be moov atom issue. Anyhow, I used AtomicParsely to fix it and now video starts playing as downloading starts.

The next problem is that user is unable to seek beyond the downloaded portion of file. I monitored the http terrific and it seems that browser is not sending any byte seek request which it does in case of WMV (In case of wmv it doesn't even work with browsers using web kit engine).

Is it possible to seek in this fashion or I've to use smooth streaming option?

-- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize pseudo streaming to accomplish this. Note that you need Silverlight to supply a start param to indicate the seek point for this. More info here: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac